# checking If integer/float contain a specific number

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, math

I try to find a way to check if number contains "2" "3" "4" "5";
So 1234 meaning is "false" and 0110 meaning is true.

I try convert float to string and check with .find() but it's too long and i can't convert properly.

```
a = Decimal(1) / Decimal(123456789)
print a

8.100000073710000670761006104E-9

a = str(a)
print a

8.100000073710000670761006104E-9
```

So please help me (:

edit:

I have a calculation formula and want to refine results. so i can use result as an input and calculate original number.

it's some kind of encription algoritm and need special number set.

for example

9,9989001209866914639389667136615e-8

is in my set cause

1 / 9,9989001209866914639389667136615e-8 = 10001100

1 / 10001100 = 9,9989001209866914639389667136615e-8

also, number source has been generated seperately. i try to read source and refine only accepted numbers.

Comment: You are trying to see if an irrational number contain a specific digit?

Comment: Can you give more detail on the format of the output you expect?

Comment: Also, if I may, what is your underlying problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: imho, the problem you are trying to solve is not well defined. What's the correct answer if the scientific notation has "4", but the normal hasn't? It means the answer can be different depending on the formatting. What about the irrational numbers where you can't check every single digit? What about the precision and rounding strategy that also affect the actual digits?

Comment: I have a calculation formula and want to refine results. i can use result as an input and calculate what first input is in a another code. it's some kind of encription algoritm and need special number set.

Comment: for example 9,9989001209866914639389667136615e-8 is in my set cause 1 / 9,9989001209866914639389667136615e-8 = 10001100

Comment: also, number source has been generated seperately. my original code read source and refine only accepted numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem well, you could try using regular expressions. Here's an interactive way to play around with regular expressions given your problem: https://regex101.com/r/i2mZmK/2/

And a potential solution in python:

```
import re
from decimal import * 

regex = re.compile(r"(2|3|4|5)")

a = Decimal(1) / Decimal(123456789)


def check_number():
    result = regex.search(str(a))

    if result is None:
        check = True

    else:
        check = False

    return check

print(check_number())
```

Comment: this is what i looking for, thank you for your time. (:

Answer (score 1):

To divide these numbers and getting rid of scientific notation, I used the following code:

```
from decimal import *
a = '{0:f}'.format(Decimal(1)/Decimal(123456789))
print a.find('1234')
print a.find('810')
```

I am not sure of the conditions of your search in the string. But I hope that would be helpful.

Comment: it's helpful, thank you for your time. (:

Comment: You are more than welcome. Moreover, if the answer satisfies you, please accept it. It is a good practice to have for both of us.
Many Thanks,,

Comment: Sorry I'm new in here, i try but can't accept multiple answers.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realized that you accepted another one.
Thanks  for your concern man!,,
^_^

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your initial problem description. If you meant whether the reciprocal of a number contains those digits, one issue is that the majority of such results have an infinite number of digits. Writing a number like `0110` complicates matters further because that's octal in Python 2 (invalid in Python 3); its value is 72.

But one thing I can easily adress, the "too long" part. You can request arbitrary (but still finite) precision from Decimal:

```
>>> f='{:f}'.format(decimal.Context(prec=200).divide(1,1234))
>>> f[:40]
'0.00081037277147487844408427876823338735'
>>> f.index('00810372')
3
>>> f.index('00810372', 3+1)
91
```

So as it happens, the digit stream of `1/1234` repeats after 88 decimal digits. All rationals have some such loop length (1/123456789 loops after 6855006 digits). But the default Decimal context didn't produce enough digits to observe the entire loop for this number.

A proper solution to this challenge would probably involve performing the long division explicitly, and tracking the fractions encountered along the way. Then you can easily detect when you find a repetition. Something along the lines of (probably slow):

```
fractions=set()
digits=[]
while fraction not in fractions:
    digit = math.floor(fraction)
    fractions.add(fraction)
    digits.append(digit)
    fraction = (fraction-digit)*10
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def returnsomething():
    demo_number = 345.43565
    list = [2, 3, 4]
    for number in list:
      if str(number) in str(demo_number):
      return True
    return False
```

Comment: You cannot return at top-level. Is this a function body?

Comment: Edited the code. Forgot to put it inside a function,

Comment: Just fix the indentation and that will be better

Comment: Doesn't work for `demo_number = 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3`

Comment: Buzzy, if you were expecting that to be 0, you should probably read up on floating point numbers. All three of those cannot be stored exactly in a `float`, and the result is therefore not only not 0 but dependent on the order of the operations.

Comment: @Yann Vernier Why do you think I gave such an example? The OP used decimal library for that specific reason. The answer here trivializes the problem by not using it. That's why I downvoted it.